# How to form a shape out of horizontal line grid? With Processing?

Tags: 3d, processing

I was wondering how to achieve a similar effect like the shape of the letter "A" coming out of a horizontal line grid (see picture attached).
Does somebody know how to find a tutorial? How is this technique called? Can you do it with Processing? Or do you need a 3D program?

Any hint is very welcome!

[image: horizontal line grid, letter A]

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's designed for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. You need to [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those steps on one at a time. Forget the computer for a minute. How would you do this with a piece of paper and a pencil? Write out a set of instructions that somebody who has never seen this technique could follow. That list of steps is an algorithm that you can think about implementing with code. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine extruding a blurred white A shape on a black background, a [height map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heightmap) if you will.

In Processing you'd loop through each pixel in the image and map the [brightness](https://processing.org/reference/brightness_.html) of each pixel to the z axis (as you already have the x,y coordinate).

In short:

1. load or create an image of the A shape with a black background and smooth/blur the image to get smooth curves when mapping brightness to elevation
2. loop through pixels and map each pixel's brightness to a z position

Here's a commented sketch to illustrate the idea:

```
PGraphics buffer;
PShape lines;

void setup(){
  size(400,400,P3D);
  smooth(8);

  //create a PGraphics buffer to draw an "A" into and then blur it -> could use a loaded PImage
  buffer = createGraphics(400,400);
  buffer.beginDraw();
  buffer.background(0);
  buffer.textSize(270);
  buffer.text("A",110,270);
  buffer.endDraw();
  //add blur (smooth edges = smooth elevation when moving to 3D)
  buffer.filter(BLUR,8);

  //setup PShape
  int hSpacing = 1;                //horizontal spacing
  int vSpacing = 9;                //vertical spacing
  float maxHeight = 30;            //maximum height (when brightness is mapped to elevation)             
  int lineStroke = color(255);

  float hw = buffer.width * 0.5;   //half width
  float hh = buffer.height * 0.5;  //half height


  lines = createShape(GROUP);
  //scan image on Y axis (skipping based on vertical spacing)
  for(int y = 0 ; y < buffer.height; y += vSpacing){
    //create a a shape made of lines
    PShape line = createShape();
    line.beginShape(LINES);
    line.stroke(lineStroke);
    line.strokeWeight(3);
    //scan image on X axis
    for(int x = 0; x < buffer.width; x += hSpacing){
      //if we're not at the last pixel
      if(x < buffer.width - 1){
        //calculate the next x position
        int nextX = x+1;
        //calculate the brightness for the current and next pixel
        float currentPixelBrightness = brightness(buffer.get(x,y));
        float nextPixelBrightness    = brightness(buffer.get(nextX,y));
        //map brightness levels to elevation
        float currentZ = map(currentPixelBrightness,0.0,255.0,0,maxHeight);
        float nextZ    = map(nextPixelBrightness,0.0,255.0,0,maxHeight);
        //add a line between the current and next pixel using the calculated elevations, but offseting by half the image's with so the PShape pivot is at the centre
        line.vertex(x - hw,y - hh,currentZ);
        line.vertex(nextX - hw,y - hh,nextZ);

      }
    }
    //finish the lines shape and add it to the main PShape
    line.endShape();
    lines.addChild(line);
  } 

}
void draw(){
  background(0);
  //debug mode - if mouse is pressed just render the 2D image
  if(mousePressed){
    image(buffer,0,0);
    return;
  }
  //otherwise render the 3D image, rotating on X axis based on mouse X position
  translate(width * 0.5,height * 0.5,0);
  rotateX(map(mouseX,0,width,-PI,PI));
  shape(lines,0,0);
}
```

There are multiple ways to implement this.
This is just one option. Bare in mind the code isn't optimised for speed, instead left more verbose so it's easier to understand and tweak.

[image: demo 1]

[image: demo 2]

Feel free to play with the available variables and values (e.g. text size, blur amount, max. height, horizontal and vertical spacing, etc.), practice playing with [createShape()](https://processing.org/reference/createShape_.html)(e.g. expand the horizontal lines, etc.)...overall, have fun!

This proves you don't really need to use a 3D program unless you really want to.

If you wanted to use one, Photoshop Extended has a 3D depth map option and most 3D editor allow you to create a mesh from a height map, to which you could apply a stripped texture.

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer and the commented code. I will check it out immediately!