# Processing - Custom Characters/Text

Tags: java, processing

I'm new to Processing. I'm trying to create custom characters/text in order to create a simple interactive lyrics video (i'd like my text to be something like this: [Lyrics Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mq9zhpBweDk)).

What I want to do is to be able to insert stripes, points, circles inside a letter/text as shown in the video.

So far i followed the material i found here: [Processing tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/typography/).

The problem is that the only thing i can do is change the font,dimension, color ecc... but i'm not capable of adding stripes to my letters, or color them with 2 different colors (this is an [Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YltP-5bVOqE) in processing of what i'd like to do)

How do i create *custom text* in processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of techniques that should help you achieve the visuals you're after with type.

1. You can rasterise/read text pixels and use those as a height map as a way to create 3D geometry. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861020/how-to-form-a-shape-out-of-horizontal-line-grid-with-processing/44876393#44876393) [image: 3D shape from text height map]
2. You can use the text glyph characteristics(vertices) to create 3D shapes are needed. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52818958/createfont-from-string/52820994#52820994)[image: glyph vertices demos]
3. You can use a library like [Geomerative](http://www.ricardmarxer.com/geomerative/) text/shape operations beyond Processing's built-in

Overall the idea is:

- process the text (extract pixels/curves/etc.)
- use those as inputs for 3D geometry
- manipulate/animate 3D geometry as needed (e.g. extrude, subdivide, use particles to flow around the geometry, etc.)

Have fun!